# Convert UTC DateTime to local datetime does not show correctly in swift

Tags: swift

I am using swift 4. I need to convert my UTC Time to local time.But it shows two hour before. I am now Living in dhaka with GMT+6. Here is code i used ..

```
var date:String = "2020-02-10 14:30:57 PM"
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss a"
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")

    let dt = dateFormatter.date(from: date)
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd h:mm a"
    let convertedLocalTime = dateFormatter.string(from: dt!)
    tv_time.text = convertedLocalTime
    print("convertedLocalTime-->",convertedLocalTime)
```

It shows `2020-02-10 6:30 PM` But now 8.30 PM . What is the wrong with the code
Please help me

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant but "14:30:57 PM" is not a valid time.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson this "2020-02-10 14:30:57 PM" come from server. if i remove PM it is working fin

Comment: Maybe you need to manually check the server data to determine if you need to modify it.

Answer (score -2):

Your input data is not correctly formatted.

If you can use a correct format for the input data:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss"
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
// set the date in UTC
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2020-02-10 14:30:57")

dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
// String representation of the date for local time
let s = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
```

this snippet sets s to "2020-02-10 15:30:57" which is correct for Germany.

Otherwise you have to correct the format of your input data, e.g. delete the "PM" from the 24h format string.

Comment: As you wrote above "2020-02-10 14:30:57 PM" is not a correct time format.
date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2020-02-10 14:30:57 PM") does not create the expected time

Comment: So you made an answer that is not relevant to the issue?

Comment: The question was: " I need to convert my UTC Time to local time" I think the answer solves this problem!

Comment: OP has already commented that removing PM will fix the issue so your code is more or less a copy of the code posted in the question with the difference that your code delivers a string with the date in the wrong format,  "yyyy-MM-dd h:mm a" is the expected output.

Comment: I think I answered before the OP commented,  -- no need to discuss -- I'm out!